# Recreate dead threads after a fork

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, x86, fork

As you might know, all threads in the application die in a forked process, other than the thread doing the fork. However, I plan to ressurrect those threads in the forked process by calling **pthread_create** and using **pthread_attr_setstack**, so as to assign the newly created threads the same stack as the dead threads. Something like as follows.

```
// stackAddr and stacksize taken from the dead thread    
pthread_attr_setstack(&attr, stackAddr, stacksize);
rc = pthread_create(&thread, &attr, threadRoutine, NULL);
```

However, I would still need to get the CPU register values, such as stack pointer, base pointer, instruction pointer etc, to restart threads from the same point. How can I do that? And what else do I need to do to successfully achieve my goal?

Also note that I'm using a 64-bit architecture. What additional difficulties would it have as compared to 32-bit one?

Comment: Just as difficult on 64 bit as 32 bit.

Comment: To clarify, you talk about processes flagged as EXIT_DEAD or as EXIT_ZOMBIE? I assume EXIT_ZOMBIE as this shouldn't be possible for EXIT_DEAD.

Comment: "As you might know, all threads in the application die in a forked process" - is that so? To my knowledge, `pthread_create` only calls `clone` (with a combination of flags, such as `CLONE_VM|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SIGHAND` or similar), effectively creating another process with shared memory, same threadgroup, etc. `fork` on the other hand, calls `clone` without those flags, creating another process with "separate everything", but not touching any of the existing processes at all (i.e. a process with 5 threads forking will still have 5 thread-processes, and there will be another separate process).

Comment: Have you looked at `pthread_atfork`?  I don't see how you avoid mutexes, condvars, etc., from getting corrupted w/o that kind of facility.  Even with them this seems pretty hairy and fragile.

Comment: I thought I had read somewhere that mixing threads and fork calls was a bad idea. Resurrecting threads after a fork (I think) takes bad ideas to a whole new level. I don't know if it's possible, I don't think it's a good idea even if it is, and I'm willing to bet there's a much better way to do whatever you really want to do.

Comment: This seems like an unusual task. Would you mind enlightening us with a little motivation for doing this? I'm not saying you should abandon your design, but I'm very curious what the use case is for this functionality.

Comment: I think he's trying to port a solaris app to linux. Solaris has a forkall call so he's probably come up with an architecture that relies on it.

Comment: @MetallicPriest I knew it! Haha, a large part of my research is in application checkpointing. Just confirming my suspicions :-). Thanks.

Comment: @denniston: maybe you can help a bit here then :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possible ways to shoot yourself in the foot and lose hair^W^W^W^W^W^W^W^Wtry to do this:

- Try to force each thread into calling `getcontext()` before the `fork()`, and then restore the context of each thread via `setcontext()`. Probably won't work, but you can try for fun.
- Save `ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS)`, `ptrace(PTRACE_GETFPREGS)`, and restore with `ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS)`, `ptrace(PTRACE_SETFPREGS)`.

Comment: Instead of doing getcontext/setcontext, cant I use setjmp/longjmp? I was thinking of doing that.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Possibly, but as I said for `setcontext()`, I don't have much hope in that approach.

Answer (score 2):

The other threads in the current process aren't killed by a fork -- they're still there and running in the parent.  The problem you seem to have is that `fork` only forks a SINGLE thread in the current procces, creating a new process running one thread with a copy of all non-thread resources in the parent.

What you apparently want is a way of duplicating an entire multithreaded task, forking all the threads in it and creating a new process/task with the same number of threads.

In order to do THAT, you would need to find and pause all the other threads in the process, dump their current state (including all locks they hold), fork a new process, and then (re)create each of those other threads in the child, rewiring the lock state to refer to the new child threads where needed.

Unfortunately, the POSIX pthread interface is hopelessly underspecified, and provides no way of doing that.  In particular, it lacks any sort of reflective interface allowing you to figure out what threads are actually running.

If you want to try to do this anyway, I can see two ways of trying to approach this:

- poke around in /proc/self/task to figure out what threads are running in your process, effectively getting that reflective interface in a highly non-portable way.  You'll likely end up having to ptrace(2) the other threads to get their internal state.  This will be very difficult.
- wrap the pthreads library -- instead of using library directly, intercept every call and keep track of all the threads/mutexes/locks that get created, so that you have that information available when you want to fork.  This will work fine as long as you don't want to use any third-party libraries that use pthreads

The second option is much easier (and somewhat portable), but only works well if you have access to all the source code of your entire application, and can modify it to use your wrappers properly.

Comment: cant I combine my above approach with setjmp/longjmp. Just assume that I do fork when there are no locks held, like at barrier points. Wouldn't it be possible. It looks like to me.

Comment: One man's "hopelessly underspecified" is another's "cleanly abstracted".  Not specifying things like the internals of locks allows implementers the freedom to do things in the best way for their environment.

Comment: @caf: with a proper spec you can specify things like the behavior of locks in a way that allows a program to manage them while still allowing implementers freedom to do things the best way for their environment.

Comment: @MatallicPriest -- if you have a way of quiescing threads (allowing them to run to some point where they hold no locks, and then pausing them), then you can use that to solve the lock management problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just googling around I found that solaris has a forkall() call that does exactly what you want, see the documentation here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1601/gen-1.html

I assume you're running on linux, but it is possible to run solaris on x86 hardware. So maybe that is an option for you.

Comment: Yes I know, I already used it in my program, but now I want to do it in Linux.

Comment: oh, ha...you're probably porting a solaris program to linux.